# Camunda 8: External form to complete User Task

Tags: camunda, zeebe

[Process-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbejw.png) I have a simple process. I use the form from my web application, when user submit the form, the back-end will start new process instance then send the form data and complete userTask:

- Step 1: Submit form
- Step 2: Start new process instance
- Step 3: Use processInstanceKey to find taskId of CREATED task
- Step 4: Send form data as variables and complete task with taskId

But in step 3 return empty task list because of the delay between processing in zeebe and processing in Operate, Tasklist(https://forum.camunda.io/t/processinstance-not-created-yet-on-whencomplete-callback-of-newcreateinstancecommand/44370)

So any solutions to solve this problem?